# Does the ENDURANCE.GAMER achievement require you to play the game in one sitting on Normal, or will Easy cut it?

Tags: achievements, bit-trip-beat

The achievement description reads:

> Beat the game in one sitting without getting a game over.

That means beating the game on Easy will also cut it, right?

Answer (score 5):

Wrong. I just beat the entire game in one sitting on Easy without getting a game over and I didn't get the achievement.

Apparently, you must spend those 45 minutes on Normal difficulty.

Comment: Well that's just going to make it that much harder to join the elusive 0.5% that do have the achievement

Comment: @jaminja Not really, once you reach some proficiency in all levels Easy is just as hard as Normal, but it gives you much more points (multiplier grows twice as fast).